# Angular 2 automatic fill-in

Tags: angular

An Angular 2 form with three hierarchical fields which, most of the time, should have the same values, but sometimes don't. To speed data-entry, I'd like the three field contents to be synchronized to subsequent fields until a modification is made to a field.

**For example**
If I type "apples" in the first field, the field values should be:

```
apples
apples
apples
```

and if I continue by tabbing to the second field and type `, pears`, the field values should be (i.e., the third field is still tracking the second):

```
apples
apples, pears
apples, pears
```

and if I continue by tabbing to the third field and type `, and oranges`, the field values should be:

```
apples
apples, pears
apples, pears, and oranges
```

and if I continue by shift-tabbing back to the second field and type `, and strawberries`, the field values should be:

```
apples
apples, pears, and strawberries
apples, pears, and oranges
```

I shouldn't have to tab into the fields for a submit to be successful. If I hit enter on the first scenario above with `apples` in all fields, the three fields should submit `apples`.

This obviously **doesn't work**:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="one">
<input [(ngModel)]="two"   value="{{one}}">
<input [(ngModel)]="three" value="{{two}}">
```

Listening to the stream of events from a `ControlGroup` seems promising:

```
this.form.valueChanges
  .subscribe(
    v => { 
      console.log("change: ", JSON.stringify(v));
    }
  );
```

but the mapping might be a lot of code. [Here's plnkr which doesnt' work, yet, along these line.](https://plnkr.co/edit/lFi4rO?p=preview)

**Is there a clean way in Angular 2 to achieve this?**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understood your question but I think this should do what you want:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="one" #ione (blur)="itwo.value ? null : itwo.value = 'two'">
<input [(ngModel)]="two" #itwo (blur)="ithree.value ? null : ithree.value = 'three'">
<input [(ngModel)]="three" #ithree value="{{three}}">
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/sbuAmH?p=preview)

Comment: ["Cannot reassign a variable binding one"](https://plnkr.co/edit/KpwqHvi5z8zzFgk92XV5?p=preview)

Comment: Sorry, there was a name collision. I updated my answer.

Comment: [This plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/KpwqHvi5z8zzFgk92XV5?p=preview) is closer but 3 isn't updated when a change is made in 2.

Comment: Maybe I misinterpreted your question. I thought it should only be updated the first time when it is still empty.

Comment: I updated the question to be a bit more clear in that regard, @GZ

Comment: I think my code should allow you to do that. I hope you don't expect me to add code to calculate the values the next field should have. What if someone enters `743` instead of `12`?

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, GZ, the question is not about mapping value to different values; I've updated the question to address that...

Comment: I still don't see how the values should be calculated. The next field should get the same value as the current with one additional character that comes next in the alphabet of the last character in the current field? Sounds like you want me to write your homework.

Comment: I added a bit more to the question. Think about this way: all field values are in sync until a field value is changed at which point only downstream in-sync fields continue to be updated.

Comment: Doesn't make any sense to me. I'm out.

Comment: OK - thank you for your time, @Gunter...you did give me a few ideas.